# Why is water running down my garage wall?

Tags: leak

Help I am confused. I have a problem with water running down my garage wall. When I go in to the garage in the morning there is a little moisture on the top of the walls. However as the day goes on and as the day gets warmer water starts to run down all the back wall. I have drilled some holes in the wall to vent the place but it is making no difference. Can anyway give me any idea of what it could be. For your info the garage is a stand alone garage with 3 windows and will be used as a playroom.

Comment: Step 1: find out where the water is coming from.

Comment: Is there running water in the garage? Do you have big temperature swings between night and day? It might be condensation...

Comment: If there's an AC, then condensation on the duct lines or a clogged condensation drain are also possible. There could be leaking plumbing. The roof could have a leak, possibly even snow melting. It could be built into a hill with improper drainage. We need a lot more detail to give a good answer.

Comment: Thanks,  we have a tap but it is the other side of the garage and there is no moisture on the walls overs that side. The swing in temperature is about 12 degrees c. We have kept the three windows open. And our roof seems to be ok no leaks, so can't imagine where all the water is coming from by 4 o clock in the day you can see it has run from the top of the wall down to the bottom.

Comment: No air con and no snow lately we are not on a hill and the water seems to come from the top of the wall down. Sorry am totally lost and bewildered. Thanks for all the helps and suggestions.

Comment: Could it be raining?

Comment: If water is coming through the wall/ceiling, then the problem is behind/above it. Check the roof/attic/space above, etc. Water will travel sideways and down, so you have to locate the source. If the water is forming on the wall, then Steven's suggestion of condensation is accurate.

Comment: I wanna see pics.  I wanna see the roof. I wanna see if this is water infiltration or condensation.  In an unheated garage, I'm not buying condensation yet. Is this are partially underground?  Give us more info.

Comment: You may have a condensation issue.
Are the walls and roof insulated?
Is there a vapor or moisture retarder in use in the ceiling and/or walls?
Is the area conditioned, e.g. air conditioned or heated?
What state are you located in?
What type of roofing is in use?
Is there continuous decking below the roof covering or is the roof covering mounted on battens or purlins?
Are the walls built with masonry or wood frame?
What is the exterior finish EIFS, stucco, wood, fibercement, etc?